# Two asynchronous functions and third function to be executed after first two is executed

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Say, I have three javascript functions

1. function1 and function2 are executed asynchronously
2. function2 is to be executed after first two is executed completely

How can this be worked out?

Comment: You can use callbacks, promises, async/await or a library such as async-waterfall. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I tried all your solutions. Didn't quite work. I created a solution myself after trying for a while. Here it is:

```
let promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("promise1"), 1000);
});

let promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("promise2"), 4000);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

It creates two functions that runs the two functions as resolve. Then it is passed to Promise.all in an array, and the third function can be run in the then block of Promise.all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Promise.all() ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all))

Example from MDN:

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Comment: I am getting that promise.all could help, just be a little more descriptive so that I understand your solution clearly.

Comment: The code inside the `then()` in `Promise.all` will be executed when the two promises are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
const promise1 = fn1();
const promise2 = fn2();

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then(values => {
    // Your code
});
```

With `async/await` you have to declare `fn1` and `fn2` as async, and then:

```
const promise1 = await fn1();
const promise2 = await fn2();

// Now the two vars contain resolved promises
```

`async/await` is probably more readable, but it will take more time because `fn2()` is not executed until promise from `fn1()` is fulfilled. In the first example with `Promise.all` the two functions are called in parallel and so it will be slightly more performant.

Check this great article from Jake Archibald about `async/await` if you want to learn more: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions

Answer (score 0):

Idea of promise chaining or async await keywords should work for you. See below example for promise chaining.

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

}).then(function(result) {

}).then(function(result) {

}).then(function(result) {

});

Answer (score 0):

You can chain promises like this:

```js
function f1() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(() => resolve('f1'), 1000);
            });
        }
        function f2() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(() => resolve('f2'), 1000);
            });
        }
        function f3() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(() => resolve('f3'), 1000);
            });
        }

// Chain promises
        f1()
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res + ' done!')
            return f2()
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res + ' done!')
            return f3()
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res + ' done!')
          })
```

Or you can group promises:

```js
        function f1() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(() => resolve('f1'), 1000);
            });
        }
        function f2() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(() => resolve('f2'), 1000);
            });
        }
        function f3() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(() => resolve('f3'), 1000);
            });
        }
        
// Group promises
        Promise.all([f1(), f2()])  
          .then((responses) => {
            console.log(responses.join(', ') + ' done!')
            return f3()
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res + ' done!')
          })
```